# Authentication methods using login, password and Facebook access token using Spring Security(not OAuth)

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-security

I already implemented registration and authentication with login and password using Spring Security. I did this using [this tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-2/). But now I want to provide registration and authentication using Facebook Id. I will get Facebook user's access token on the mobile app, then I will send this access token to the my Spring server(so OAuth is not suitable), validate it using Facebook API, and get Facebook user Id.
Note that I already have table `Users` in my database with `user_id`, `login`, `password`, `fb_id` columns, so there are two variants for the registration: either user will have login and password, or user will have just Facebook account and I will use him Facebook id.

Finally, I just need to authenticate this user and return him JWT token.

Already existing code.

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

CurrentUser:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {

}
```

CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Let people login with either username or email
        User user = userRepository.findByPhone(username)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username or email : " + username)
                );

        return user;
    }

    // This method is used by JWTAuthenticationFilter
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with id : " + id)
        );

        return user;
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
    }
}
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

JwtTokenProvider:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationInMs;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {

        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(user.getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public Long getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return Long.parseLong(claims.getSubject());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

AuthController:

```
//...
 @PostMapping("/authorization")
    public AuthorizationResponse AuthauthenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getPhone(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);

        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();

        AuthorizationResponse authorizationResponse = new AuthorizationResponse(user.getId(), jwt);

        return authorizationResponse;
    }
//...
```

So, how can I achieve this goal using Spring Security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an API that

- takes the `id_token` from the client in the request body.
- Calls facebook's API to validate the `id_token` and get the user's details.
- Save or update the user in the database.
- Authenticate the user
- Create and return the JWT

Here is an example code -

```
@PostMapping("/signin/facebook")
public ResponseEntity<?> signInWithFacebook(@Valid @RequestBody FBLoginRequest loginRequest) {

    // Call facebook's API to validate id_token and get user's details

    // Register new user (Note: Also add code to check if a user already exists with the given facebookId )
    User user = new User(fbName, fbID,
            emailId, null);
    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("User Role not set."));
    user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(userRole));

    User result = userRepository.save(user);

    // Authenticate User
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.create(result);
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, userPrincipal.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    // Generate and return token
    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
}
```

I haven't added code for calling facebook's API. But that should be trivial to implement.

Comment: Pls  @don-prog do you have sample of request for facebook API? Did you use for this spring-social? Did you also create a request for Google API?

Comment: @user1089362 1. I don't use Facebook API to get user login and access_token,
 I do it on Android so I use the Facebook Android SDK. On the server side I only check if the access_token is valid, it is very default request which you can find on the web, but if you want, I can share it. 2. No, I don't use spring-social. 3. No.

Comment: UserPrincipal userPrincipal =  new UserPrincipal(username);
Thank you bro